# std::exception : use of virtual function and inheritance vs a variable

Tags: c++, exception, virtual-functions, std

What is the reason that `std::exception` is designed in a way that to create a new type of exception, A derived class is made which overrides the `virtual what()` function, than make a class that could hold a string and return that on `what()`?

```
class exception
{
    std::string msg;
public:
    exception(std::string _msg) : msg(_msg) {}
    void set(std::string _msg) { msg = _msg; }
    std:string what() { return msg; }
};
```

And each error `(bad_alloc, logical_error ...)` could be an instance of the class rather than a derived class.

What is the reason that virtual functions and inheritance is used rather than the above approach ?

Comment: [`std::exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) is the abstract interface. If you want a concrete base-class that does what you want, consider [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error)

Comment: Your `exception` does memory allocation, so is mostly "incompatible" with `std::bad_alloc` exception.

Comment: @Jarod42 how about if it was a fixed length character array ?

Comment: Then your class would not be directly usable for longer message. There are some thread-of to do. the virtual way seems better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catch block can't be template meaning that a type to witch the exception is implicitly convertible must be specified.

having one interface for exception(`std::exception`) allow catching any exception and getting there error message without knowing or caring about the real type of the exception. but also let the user choose a more precise type like `std::runtime_error` if he want to catch only those exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Both can be used and are perfectly fine. The standard library uses this approach to make different 'categories' of exceptions.